# Read or write Mc Predictive Intelligence data

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, einstein-recommendations

I would like to read or write the Predictive Intelligence data with query or SOAP API.

Are there DataExtension where the data is saved?

I saw that there are DataExtension with 'IGO_' prefix like the DataExtension 'IGO_PRODUCTS', 'IGO_VIEWS', etc., but in our Org are empty

Comment: Nobody can answer my help request? Then, do I need to open a case in Salesforce support?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to create your own Data extension with fields as described [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/predictive_intelligence/predictive_intelligence_integration/contacts_and_raw_data_integration/contact_builder_relationship/).

Then you can write SQL query in Email -> Interaction -> Query and select the desired Data extension as Target DE e.g.

SQL: Select sku, user_id, session_id, search, timestamp from IGO_Views

Target DE: myIGO_Views (with Append)

You can either run this SQL manually and schedule via Automation Studio to populate data in these data extensions.

NOTE: The PI DEs like IGO_Views cannot be viewed directly but can be queried via SQL.